# R: Webscraping Wayback Machine

Tags: html, r, web-scraping

I am working with the R programming language.

For the following website : https://covid.cdc.gov/covid-data-tracker/ - I am trying to get all versions of this website that are available on WayBackMachine (along with the month and time). The final result should look something like this:

```
         date                                                                                links     time
1 Jan-01-2023 https://web.archive.org/web/20230101000547/https://covid.cdc.gov/covid-data-tracker/ 00:05:47
2 Jan-01-2023 https://web.archive.org/web/20230101000557/https://covid.cdc.gov/covid-data-tracker/ 00:05-57
```

Here is what I tried so far:

**Step 1:** First, I inspected the HTML source code (within "elements") and copied/pasted it into a notepad file:

[image]

**Step 2:** Then, I imported this into R and parsed the resulting html for the link structure:

```
file <- "cdc.txt"

text <- readLines(file)

html <- paste(text, collapse = "\n")

pattern1 <- '/web/\\d+/https://covid\\.cdc\\.gov/covid-data-tracker/[^"]+'

links <- regmatches(html, gregexpr(pattern1, html))[[1]]
```

But this is not working :

```
> links
character(0)
```

**Can someone please show me if there is an easier way to do this?**

Thanks!

**Note:**

- I am trying to learn how to do this in general (i.e. for any websites on WayBackMachine - the Covid Data Tracker is just an placeholder example for this question)
- I realize that there might be much more efficient ways to do this - I open to learning about different approaches!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Archive.org provides [Wayback CDX API](https://archive.org/developers/wayback-cdx-server.html#id1) for looking up captures, it returns timestamps along with original urls in tabular form or JSON. Such queries can be made with `read.table()` alone, links to specific captures can then be constructed from `timestamp` and `original` columns and base URL.

```r
read.table("https://web.archive.org/cdx/search/cdx?url=covid.cdc.gov/covid-data-tracker/&limit=5", 
           col.names = c("urlkey","timestamp","original","mimetype","statuscode","digest","length"),
           colClasses = "character")
#>                              urlkey      timestamp
#> 1 gov,cdc,covid)/covid-data-tracker 20200824224244
#> 2 gov,cdc,covid)/covid-data-tracker 20200825013347
#> 3 gov,cdc,covid)/covid-data-tracker 20200825024622
#> 4 gov,cdc,covid)/covid-data-tracker 20200825042657
#> 5 gov,cdc,covid)/covid-data-tracker 20200825050018
#>                                    original  mimetype statuscode
#> 1 https://covid.cdc.gov/covid-data-tracker/ text/html        200
#> 2 https://covid.cdc.gov/covid-data-tracker/ text/html        200
#> 3 https://covid.cdc.gov/covid-data-tracker/ text/html        200
#> 4 https://covid.cdc.gov/covid-data-tracker/ text/html        200
#> 5 https://covid.cdc.gov/covid-data-tracker/ text/html        200
#>                             digest length
#> 1 APS6SXNXBXCJU3P4N23WH4XCVDVZQYAD   5342
#> 2 XFEMFRGXIPWM4K5F6CBIYDSOFIGCUBQZ   5370
#> 3 TVQKZHRM452CFX4RIORWGSMK5PG3PAPR   5343
#> 4 XZDLPJ6EQIXEO4SUFQTFEX4S6SF7O4GT   5370
#> 5 A4J63TFU7HMZQE5KFTSLBD6EFNZ4IBZ4   5373
```

To make it a bit more convenient to work with, we can customize API request with `httr` / `httr2`, for example, and pass the response through `readr` / `dplyr` / `lubridate` pipeline:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(httr2)
library(readr)

archive_links <- request("https://web.archive.org/cdx/search/cdx") %>% 
  # set query parameters
  req_url_query(
    url      = "covid.cdc.gov/covid-data-tracker/",
    filter   = "statuscode:200", # include only succesful captures where HTTP status code was 200
    collapse = "timestamp:8",    # limit to 1 capt. per day by comparing first 8 digits of timestamp: <20200824>224244
    limit    = 10,               # limit the number of returned values
    # output = "json"            # request json output, includes column names
  ) %>% 
  req_perform() %>%
  # pass http response string to read_table() for pasring
  resp_body_string() %>% 
  read_table(col_names = c("urlkey","timestamp","original","mimetype","statuscode","digest","length"),
             col_types = cols_only(timestamp = "c",
                                   original  = "c",
                                   mimetype  = "c",
                                   length    = "i")) %>% 
  mutate(link = paste("https://web.archive.org/web", timestamp, original, sep = "/") %>% tibble::char(shorten = "front"),
         timestamp = lubridate::ymd_hms(timestamp)) %>% 
  select(timestamp, link, length)
archive_links
#> # A tibble: 10 × 3
#>    timestamp           link                                               length
#>    <dttm>              <char>                                              <int>
#>  1 2020-08-24 22:42:44 …4224244/https://covid.cdc.gov/covid-data-tracker/   5342
#>  2 2020-08-25 01:33:47 …5013347/https://covid.cdc.gov/covid-data-tracker/   5370
#>  3 2020-08-26 02:37:09 …6023709/https://covid.cdc.gov/covid-data-tracker/   5371
#>  4 2020-08-27 01:05:48 …7010548/https://covid.cdc.gov/covid-data-tracker/   5703
#>  5 2020-08-28 02:23:26 …8022326/https://covid.cdc.gov/covid-data-tracker/  31177
#>  6 2020-08-29 02:01:27 …9020127/https://covid.cdc.gov/covid-data-tracker/  31237
#>  7 2020-08-30 00:06:31 …0000631/https://covid.cdc.gov/covid-data-tracker/  31218
#>  8 2020-08-31 00:18:29 …1001829/https://covid.cdc.gov/covid-data-tracker/  31640
#>  9 2020-09-01 02:30:30 …1023030/https://covid.cdc.gov/covid-data-tracker/  31257
#> 10 2020-09-02 04:08:31 …2040831/https://covid.cdc.gov/covid-data-tracker/  31654

# first capture:
archive_links$link[1]
#> <pillar_char<[1]>
#> [1] https://web.archive.org/web/20200824224244/https://covid.cdc.gov/covid-data-tracker/
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-02 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

There are also Archive.org client libraries for R, e.g.
https://github.com/liserman/archiveRetriever & https://hrbrmstr.github.io/wayback/ , though the query interface for the first is bit odd, and the other is currently not available through CRAN.

Comment: @margsul: thank you so much for your answer! The api in this case is free? And it does not require you to even register for an account? Thank you!

Comment: CDX access to public data is not limited by any means to my knowledge, not sure if I'd call it "free" -- donations keep it running and archive.org welcomes all supporters.

Answer (score 1):

This is really two questions. The html is generated client side rather than server side. This is why you cannot just request the html from R to get what you need, and end up copying and pasting from Developer Tools. You can automate this by using [RSelenium](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSelenium/vignettes/basics.html). The docs are extensive so I won't cover that in the answer.

You should also use a parser like [rvest](https://rvest.tidyverse.org/) to parse the html, [rather than regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454). In this case, to get the output you want, that would look something like:

```r
library(rvest)

url <- "wayback.html"
page <- read_html(url)

# Find correct links
links <- page |>
    html_elements("a") |>
    html_attr("href") |>
    grep("/web/\\d.+/https://covid.cdc.gov/covid-data-tracker/$", x = _, value = T)

# Create dates
dates <- as.Date(
    gsub("/web/(\\d{8}).+$", "\\1", links),
    format = "%Y%m%d"
)

# Prepend base URL
links <- paste0("https://web.archive.org/", links)

dat <- data.frame(dates, links)
head(dat)

#        dates                                                                                 links
# 1 2020-08-24 https://web.archive.org//web/20200824224244/https://covid.cdc.gov/covid-data-tracker/
# 2 2023-06-30 https://web.archive.org//web/20230630234650/https://covid.cdc.gov/covid-data-tracker/
# 3 2023-06-29 https://web.archive.org//web/20230629011221/https://covid.cdc.gov/covid-data-tracker/
# 4 2023-01-01       https://web.archive.org//web/20230101/https://covid.cdc.gov/covid-data-tracker/
# 5 2023-01-02       https://web.archive.org//web/20230102/https://covid.cdc.gov/covid-data-tracker/
# 6 2023-01-03       https://web.archive.org//web/20230103/https://covid.cdc.gov/covid-data-tracker/
```

Comment: @ SamR: Thank you so much for your answer! I tried running your code and get the following errors:

Comment: > library(rvest)
> 
> url <- "wayback.html"
> page <- read_html(url)
Error: 'wayback.html' does not exist in current working directory ('C:/Users/me/OneDrive/Documents').
> 
> # Find correct links
> links <- page |>
+     html_elements("a") |>
+     html_attr("href") |>
+     grep("/web/\\d.+/https://covid.cdc.gov/covid-data-tracker/$", x = _, value = T)
Error: unexpected input in:
"    html_attr("href") |>
    grep("/web/\\d.+/https://covid.cdc.gov/covid-data-tracker/$", x = _"

Comment: Do I need to replace the URL <- "" with the actual website?

Comment: No that won't work. You'll need selenium if you want to do that. That's the copied and pasted html that you had saved as `cdc.txt`. I should have made that clearer.