# How do you scrape the date a page was archived on the Wayback machine using R?

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I would like to scrape the date a page was archived. I have tried using both the xpath and the selector. I think that the reason I might not be able to scrape the date is because the date appears to be embedded in a banner. The date in question is at the top right of the page (June 4, 2011). Any suggestions?

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)

# Specify the URL
url <- "https://web.archive.org/web/20110604005152/https://www.airnav.com/fuel/report.html"

# Read the webpage
webpage <- read_html(url)

# Extract the date scraped
date_scraped <- webpage %>%
  html_node(xpath = '//*[@id="displayDayEl"]') %>%
  html_text()
```

Comment: I answered a question about this recently [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76596578/r-webscraping-wayback-machine) but the other answer is better as basically it's this: you don't, there's an API.

Comment: the date is in the url. Why do more than just pluck from there?