# How to scrape the underlying links from the calendar in the wayback machine using R

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

Manually copying each link from the Wayback Machine's calendar can be tedious. I tried to automate the process, but it didn't give the correct links.

I'm interested in scraping the url's from all the blue calendar dots. How can I accomplish this?

```
library(rvest)
wayback_url <- "https://web.archive.org/web/20160215000000*/https://www.airnav.com/fuel/report.html"

# Function to scrape links from a given Wayback Machine URL
scrape_links <- function(url) {
  page <- read_html(url)
  links <- page %>%
    html_nodes("a") %>%
    html_attr("href")
  return(links)
}

links <- scrape_links(wayback_url)
```

Comment: [Does this help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76596578/r-webscraping-wayback-machine) ? Maybe consider using the Wayback CDX API.